# How to observe how much CPU time a request consumes on a thread?

Tags: runtime, scheduled-tasks, interrupt

Thank you for taking the time to read my query.

Normally you have multiple threads spawned to handle in incoming request. I'm trying to identify the amount of CPU time used by a bunch of threads to satisfy an incoming request.

The issue is that there are so many models of concurrency and parallelism (for example, you can have a single thread handling multiple requests), just using `sched_runtime` isn't an option.

On the other hand, interrupts+handlers are an easy way to find this info, however I don't know how this would work with multiple threads, the solution would not be language independent, and a ton of info about what exactly triggered the interrupt would be lost.

Any suggestions on what how I could move forward with this?

Comment: Would it be easier to observe how much CPU is not used by those threads?  Maybe another thread that has lower priority could measure the left-over time?

Comment: @MartinJames Unfortunately that won't really give exact numbers. Let's say if on a single thread, there are multiple requests requiring different amounts of CPU being concurrently processed. An external thread would not have insights about this info.